# Understanding how Lambda closure type has deleted default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, lambda, default

From 5.1.2

> [19] The closure type associated with a lambda-expression **has a deleted (8.4.3) default constructor** and a deleted
>   copy assignment operator. It has an implicitly-declared copy constructor (12.8) and may have an implicitlydeclared
>   move constructor (12.8). [ Note: The copy/move constructor is implicitly defined in the same way
>   as any other implicitly declared copy/move constructor would be implicitly defined. —end note ]

I'm reading through C++ Primer 14.8.1 which explains lambda expressions being translated by the compiler in to an unnamed object of an unnamed class. How is it I can I define objects of lambda functions which do not contain a lambda capture, if the default constructor is deleted?

```
 auto g = [](){};
```

Is this not conceptually the same as...

```
 class lambdaClass{
 public:
      lambdaClass() = delete;
      lambdaClass& operator=(const lambdaClass&) = delete;
      void operator()(){ }

      //copy/move constructor and destructor implicitly defined
};

auto g = lambdaClass(); //would be an error since default is deleted.
```

If there was a capture then a constructor *other* than the default constructor would be defined and it would be okay to initialise objects of such (as long as a parameter was passed). But if there is no capture and the default constructor is deleted, it doesn't seem consistent conceptually that a lambda class object can be created.

Edit: Hmm, maybe the conception that the lambda class creates constructors depending on its lambda captures is unfounded despite this being how it's described in C++ Primer (I can find no quote of it in the standard), because the following code does not work even though I would expect it to conceptually:

```
int sz = 2;
auto a = [sz](){ return sz;};
decltype(a) b(10); //compiler error
decltype(a) b = a; //all good though
```

Comment: You can still do something like `auto g = lambdaClass(dummyLambdaTag{})`.

Comment: @Jarod42 what would this `dummyLambdatag`? Wouldn't it have to be a lmabda, which seems to lead to a chicken and egg situation

Comment: @Baruch: `dummyLambdatag` would be an empty struct. A class non default constructible might have constructor taking parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relationship between a **closure** to **lambda** is similar to **object** to **class**.

The *C++11 standard* says that the **closure!** type has no default constructor, and that is correct because it doesn't say it has no constructor.

The lambda is used to create a closure. But your quoted paragraph will change for *C++14*.

```
ClosureType() = delete;                     // (until C++14)
ClosureType(const ClosureType& ) = default; // (since C++14)
ClosureType(ClosureType&& ) = default;      // (since C++14)
```

> Closure types are not [DefaultConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible). Closure types have `a deleted (until C++14)` `no (since C++14)` default constructor. The copy constructor and the move constructor are `implicitly-declared (until C++14)` declared `as defaulted (since C++14)` and may be implicitly-defined according to the usual rules for copy constructors and move constructors.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: So I suppose it must create the object using some sort of dummy parameter like @Jarod42 mentions, if constructors do exist for it then. Thanks.

Comment: A `lambda` is simply used to create an instance of `ClosureType`.

Comment: Note; C++20 will change this in the sense that a lambda without any captures may be default constructed.

Answer (score 0):

because the right side of assignment is a temp object(rvalue), so the 'g' is assigned by move assignment