# error : a lambda closure type has a deleted default constructor

Tags: c++, lambda, std

when I try to build below code, I met error

```
    int a = 10;
    auto func = [a]() -> int
    {
        return 10;
    };

    std::array<decltype(func), 2> array;
```

the error is

```
/usr/include/c++/11/array:95:12: note: ‘std::array<Task_Test_make_task_test_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()>, 2>::array()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   95 |     struct array
      |            ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/array:95:12: error: use of deleted function ‘Task_Test_make_task_test_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()>::<lambda>()’
Task_Test.cpp:46:23: note: a lambda closure type has a deleted default constructor
   46 |         auto func = [a]() -> int
```

is there anyway to fix this error?

I found that if I didn't capture "a", it is ok. but is there no way to capture the variable when above situation?

Comment: what is the actual aim? In your example there is no reason to capture `a`.

Comment: Capturing a variable means creating a non-static field in lambda class that must be initialized when class instance is created.

Comment: Well, compiler tells already: The closure type has a deleted default constructor – obviously there's one accepting an `int` so that the closure can be appropriately initialised with `a` – but how would you now get the `a` into the `std::array`'s default constructor???

Comment: [Why closure types / lambdas have no default constructor in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193353/why-closure-types-lambdas-have-no-default-constructor-in-c) and [Understanding how Lambda closure type has deleted default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911729/understanding-how-lambda-closure-type-has-deleted-default-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

> is there anyway to fix this error?

Declare it as this:

```
std::array<std::function<int()>, 2> arr;
```

Also of note probably not a good idea to declare a variable of type `std::array` with the name `array`. So I renamed it to just `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the nonexistance of a default constructor for the lambda with capture. You can avoid the default construction like this:

```
std::array<decltype(func), 2> array{func,func};
```

With CTAD since C++17:

```
std::array array{func,func};
```

Comment: The big question now remains: What would be the use case for such array???

Comment: @Aconcagua i suppose OP has simplified their example, maybe they simplified it too much, and certainly literally the code makes no sense.